# I am having error : "Inbox" -- Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I am writing a simple smart contract namely 'inbox.sol'. I am using truffle framework to test and deploy it to the rinkeby network using Infura API. I am having this error. Please help. I'm a beginner.

[This is deployed contract in migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di0rb.png)

[This is my smart contract code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UsdM.png)

[error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDuCs.png)

Comment: Apparently you need to set a constructor parameter

Comment: Next time, please share the code instead of images. This will be more helpful for people who want to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contract has a constructor and expects an argument.

```
constructor(string memory initialMessage) public {
        message = initialMessage;
    }
```

So when you deploy it you have to pass an argument.

```
const Inbox = artifacts.require("Inbox");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  // passing an argument 
  deployer.deploy(Inbox, "myInitialMessage");
};
```